# Effective way of using RelativePanel for UWP App

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, win-universal-app

I am creating an UWP Application, and in my App I want structure like default Mail App, where there is a Listview which has list of all the mails and when user click on that mail it open on the right side of it.

I read about RelativePanel and tried to use that in my App, it works pretty well for now, below is the xaml which I am using:

```
   <RelativePanel Grid.Row="1">

        <Frame x:Name="listFrame" 
               Width="600"
               Height="500"/>

        <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"
               RelativePanel.RightOf="listFrame"
               Width="600"
               Height="500" />


    </RelativePanel>
```

For Tablet/PC it works well and when I open it in Mobile view it automatically adapt by putting contentFrame at bottom, but my concern is that should I use this for Mobile view? because keeping contentFrame is not making sense as user should not able to view content in mobile view, for that I user should click any item and than only content view gets visible and listview will gets collapse, similar to Mail App.

I am not sure which way to go for, do I need to create different UI for PC and Mobile or there is something baked in the SDK that I can use for?

I am new to UWP so didn't know much options that I can go for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "Master-Detail".

There's a sample for that in the windows-universal-sample git repo -> [Master/Detail sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlMasterDetail)

Download the sample, run it and take a look into the code. I think it's a good starting-point.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Any help on how I can have Appbar same like Mail App, on PC MasterPage list don't have appbar and DetailPage have that at Top, while on mobile both have appbar at bottom, shall I go for adaptive triggers and make visibility base on device type?

Answer (score 1):

There are many options to handle multi views for multi devices.

- Create difference views (XAML file) for each device family. Use this when your xaml changes dramatically between device families.
- Use adaptive trigger to change the visibility or re-flow your XAML, use it with `x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"` to have better performance because element will not be initialized until you change the visibility from trigger
- Check the device family in code behind and react accordingly